# Может ли иметь смысл менять ICollection<T> на IEnumerable<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, коллекции, generics, .net-4.8

У меня имеется класс Api объекта, в котором можно сделать запрос к серверу, и получить от него данные.

Класс имеет 2 метода, как асинхронное получение данных, так и синхронное (вызывает асинхронный метод путем получения объекта ожидания, и возвращает результат). Так же присутствуют 2 иветна, которые вызываются при ошибке, а так же при успешном завершении операции (все это описано в базовом классе):

```cs
internal abstract class BaseApiObject<TType, TOptions>
    : IApiObject<TType, TOptions>
    where TType : IDataObject
    where TOptions : IOptions
{
    protected readonly Client Client;

    protected BaseApiObject(Client client)
    {
        Client = client;
    }

    public event EventHandler<ICompleteArgs<TType>> Complete;
    public event EventHandler<IError> Error;

    public ICollection<TType> Get(TOptions options)
    {
        return GetAsync(options, CancellationToken.None)
            .ConfigureAwait(false)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
    }

    public abstract Task<ICollection<TType>>
        GetAsync(TOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default);

    protected Uri RequestUri(TOptions options)
    {
        return new Uri(Client.Options.BaseUri, options.Prepare(Client.Options.Token));
    }

    protected virtual void OnComplete(ICompleteArgs<TType> e)
    {
        Complete?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    protected virtual void OnError(IError e)
    {
        Error?.Invoke(this, e);
    }
}
```

Так же имеется класс наследник, который должен возвращать коллекцию данныъ при успешном завершении, и эта коллекция имеет тип `ICollection<T>`, т.к. я делаю несколько Linq запросов в коде, я подумал, а может ли иметь смысл возвращать `IEnumerable<T>` а не делать создавать коллекцию, и кидать в нее данные:

```cs
internal sealed class Years
    : BaseApiObject<IYear, IYearsOptions>, IYears
{
    internal Years(Client client)
        : base(client)
    {
    }

    public override async Task<ICollection<IYear>>
        GetAsync(IYearsOptions options, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        if (options is null)
        {
            throw new NullReferenceException(string.Format(Errors.MustBeNotNull, nameof(options)));
        }

        using (HttpRequestMessage requestMessage
            = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, RequestUri(options)))
        {
            using (HttpResponseMessage responseMessage
                = await Client.HttpClient
                    .SendAsync(requestMessage, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseContentRead, cancellationToken))
            {
                string contentString = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(contentString);
                if (!responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode
                    && responseMessage.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
                {
                    JToken errorToken = jObject[JsonFields.Error];
                    if (errorToken is null)
                    {
                        OnError(new Error(Errors.Internal));
                        throw new ApplicationException(Errors.Internal);
                    }

                    string errorMessage = errorToken.ToObject<string>();
                    OnError(new Error(errorMessage));
                    throw new OperationCanceledException(errorMessage);
                }

                if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    cancellationToken.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
                }

                YearCompleteArgs completeArgs
                    = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YearCompleteArgs>(contentString);

                JToken resultsToken = jObject[JsonFields.Results];

                if (resultsToken is null)
                {
                    OnError(new Error(Errors.Internal));
                    throw new ApplicationException(Errors.Internal);
                }

                ICollection<IYear> responseCollection = new List<IYear>(resultsToken.Count());

                IEnumerable<KodikYear> result =
                    from kodikYear
                        in resultsToken
                    select kodikYear.ToObject<KodikYear>();

                foreach (KodikYear kodikYear in result)
                {
                    responseCollection.Add(kodikYear);
                }

                completeArgs.Results = responseCollection;
                OnComplete(completeArgs);
                return responseCollection;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Код который меня беспокоит, это:

```
ICollection<IYear> responseCollection = new List<IYear>(resultsToken.Count());

IEnumerable<KodikYear> result =
    from kodikYear
        in resultsToken
    select kodikYear.ToObject<KodikYear>();

foreach (KodikYear kodikYear in result)
{
    responseCollection.Add(kodikYear);
}
```

Я вот думаю, это может ускорить формирование ответа за счет отдачи перечислителя, вместо самой коллекции, и еще даст ли это плюс, если допустим сделается сразу 2 запроса, один из которых будет идти сразу за другим?
*(понятное дело что там можно сделать просто вызов `ToList`, но я хочу добавить прерывание пополнения коллекции при отмене операции)*

Comment: Странноватый у вас код, тут и всякие `.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` и `JObject`, и зачем то проверка `if (cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)`  при вызове `ThrowIfCancellationRequested()`. Вы уверены, что только этот участок кода беспокоит вас?) Ну а по вопросу, мне кажется, вам стоит обратить внимание на `yield` и `IAsyncEnumerable` (если нужна асинхронность), тогда вы и отмену реализуете когда вам надо и будете получать данные по мере поступления.

Comment: `IAsyncEnumerable` не доступен в `.NET Framework` к сожалению.

Comment: Ох [ошибаетесь](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX01h.png). Это фича C#8, в .NET Framework она вынесена в отдельную либу, зовется `Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces`. И да, уже пора забыть о старичке Framework...

Comment: @EvgeniyZ вот когда Microsoft [накатит](https://github.com/dotnet/core/issues/5013#issuecomment-725619513) всем .NET 5 через Windows Update, тогда будет значительно прикольнее. А пока старичок есть везде, а для остального надо либо установщик .NET таскать, либо "все-в-одном" собирать.

Comment: @aepot ИМХО, это уже проблема клиента. Сейчас тоже не на всех машинах есть .NET Framework последний и вроде без труда люди ставят, а в .net core (вроде) и в .net 5 вовсе выскакивает сообщение с кнопкой "скачать". Так что, не вижу разницы в этом плане, вижу лишь геморой для разработчика, который не получит всего нового из c#9 и .net5.

Comment: Синхронный метод `Get` нужно убрать. Потребитель сам вызовет `Result` или `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` если ему будет нужно. При этом он сам сможет понять причину дедлока, в случае чего.

Comment: `throw new NullReferenceException` - это системное исключение. Вы вместо него должны бросать `ArgumentNullException`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ многие ждут еще выхода .NET 6 перед миграцией, потому что .NET 5 не LTS. Легаси нас еще долго будет преследовать. Слава богу с Framework 3.5 почти все слезли, всего 10 лет на это потребовалось. :)

Comment: `ApplicationException` - не используйте его. Оно признано ошибкой проектирования фреймворка и не рекомендуется к применению. Бросайте какое-то конкретное исключение.

Comment: `throw new OperationCanceledException` - вы бросаете это исключение в случае возникновения ошибки. Но оно должно означать именно отмену операции (пользователем).

Comment: Вообще, при использовании `Task`ов становятся не нужны события: все эти `OnError`, `OnComlete`. Таск после завершения содержит всю необходимую информацию об успехе/ошибке/отмене.

Comment: По поводу ответа на вопрос. Он отчасти холиварный. В конкретном вашем случае лучше, имхо, возвращать `IEnumerable`. Или, раз уж создан `List<T>`, то возвращать именно его (`IList`) - в этом случае можно сразу по индексу обращаться к данным.

Comment: Я бы постарался избавиться от использования `Content.ReadAsStringAsync`. И, соответственно, от `JObject` и `JsonConvert`. Применил бы `ReadAsStreamAsync`, передал бы поток в потоковый `JsonReader` и оттуда возвращал бы экземпляры `KodikYear` с помощью `yield return`. Вот тогда получится чистый `IEnumerable` без лишнего потребления памяти.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не предостерегаете наследников вашего класса `BaseApiObject` от 1 проблемы: редактируемость коллекции. Если запрос идёт из условного интернета, то возникает большой вопрос: зачем нам нужна изменяемость, если она никак на данные с сервера не влияет? Поэтому лучше возвращать `IEnumerable<T>`, а ещё лучше — `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` (оператор `yield` также не повредит).

---

Также лучше убрать синхронную версию метода `GetAsync` — `Get`: вы за пользователя выбираете, как вернуть результат в синхронном виде. Если реализация вашего метода изменится, то к чёртовой бабушке может полететь код всех пользователей вашего метода, т.е. пользователи метода зависят от её реализации. Результат-то тот же, да вот реализация другая, и проблемы другие, несмотря на результат, которые выпячиваются наружу (например, dead-lock).

Поэтому вам никогда не стоит делать методы, реализацию которых вы не можете изменить. Это тоже самое, что не использовать интерфейсы в коде на 1 млн. строк.